# PHP mysql_real_escape_string losing values

Tags: php, sql, code-injection

I have a form in which the user can modify several fields at the same time by using a checkbox. I have used mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['doby']); perfectly before, but for some reason on this case it loses the value when i try to store it in a variable. This is my code to echo the value:

```
 if(isset($_POST['edit_patient_insurance'])){

for($i=0;$i<=$_POST['n'];$i++)
{
    if($_POST['insurance'.$i]==1)
    {   

    $insurance_num = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[insurance_num.$i]); 
    $relation = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[relation.$i]); 
    $insured_cmp = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[insured_cmp.$i]); 
    $insured_nm = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['insured_nm'.$i]); 

//more POSTS here
    $insured_ssn = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ssn1']).mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ssn2']).mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ssn3']);

    $date = mktime(0,0,0, $dobm, $dobd, $doby);
    $idob=date('Y-m-d', $date);

//Try to get the mysql_real_ecape_string version
    echo $i;
    echo $insurance_num;
    echo $insured_nm;
 //Verify it's sending the correct information
    echo $_POST[insurance_num.$i];
    echo $_POST[insured_nm.$i];

    }   
}
```

}

So, when I try this, the echo for $insurance_num and $insured_nm do not return any value. But $_POST values are returned. I don't understand what is happening.

Comment: There's so much wrong with this... your array indices are using strings as if they were constants.  i.e. should be `$_POST['insured_nm'.$i]`

Comment: in addition to the above a new form structure using name="insurance_num[]" etc would make life a lot simpler

Comment: should be rewritten to `$insured_ssn = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ssn1'].$_POST['ssn2'].$_POST['ssn3']);`

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel -- true, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

mysql_real_escape_string required connection to a mysql server. Please make sure you already create a connection. Check the error log.